# How to add some common code in all the services in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having one condition i.e

```
if(localstorage.testEnv){
   env.apiUrl='testUrl.com';
 }else{
   env.apiUrl='liveUrl.com';
 }
```

I need to inject this code in all the services. Is there any way I can implement this so that their won't be any code duplication.
Also, would this code work? I am trying to update env const (apiUrl) here?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to make a Utils Service and expose all common functions in this file, in this case a function which checks testEnv from local Storage and returns the corresponding URL. In this case getAPIBaseUrl is the function.

```js
define(["../module"], function(services) {
  "use strict";
  services.service("Utils", [
    "$localStorage",
    function($localStorage) {
      this.getAPIBaseUrl = function() {
        if ($localStorage.testEnv) {
          return "testUrl.com";
        }
        return "liveUrl.com";
      };
    }
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the API url can change in the runtime, you may want to define the `apiUrl` and an AngularJS [constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant).

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('apiUrl', (function() {
  return localStorage.testEnv ? 'testUrl.com' : 'liveUrl.com'
})());

app.controller('SomeController', function(apiUrl) {
  console.log(apiUrl)
});
```

Main benefit of using a constant is that it can be injected in the configuration phase, e.g:

```
app.config(function(apiUrl) {
  console.log(apiUrl)
})
```

Comment: both are the code seems fine. I created a file name as app.constant.js , and used your code, but how should I pass $localstorage service in app.constant ?

Comment: It's not possible to inject AngularJS dependencies in `constants` without fiddling with `angular.injector`. If you need the particular service instead of the globally available `localStorage` then you should probably use a `.factory` or a `.service` instead of a `.constant`